# spring data jpa (hibernate+spring+jpa)

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I got one requirement where each company has separate database with the same schema,  in future new company might be added to same schema structure.I have to connect their company schema based on user login. So that I have to connect separate database each time when user login.I wan to use spring data JPA to take care of connection.Only I will configure new schema credential in properties file.Is there any way we can add dynamic database schema which uses same model classes.All should happen in run time only.

Comment: Can't you have different schemas for each company, all in one database? I think that would be much easier

Comment: Yes, it may be possible. But my problem is to connect different schema with spring data jpa. How i will achieve this due to schema may added dynamically.Spring need at configuration time only.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are asking about multi-tenant support. You can create a `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` something like this:

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
        DataSource dataSource,
        MultiTenantConnectionProvider multiTenantConnectionProvider,
        CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver tenantIdentifierResolver) {

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emfBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    emfBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
    emfBean.setPackagesToScan(Application.class.getPackage().getName());
    emfBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());

    Map<String, Object> jpaProperties = new HashMap<>();
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");

    // Improved naming strategy deprecated as of hibernate 5.0
    // jpaProperties.put("hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy", "org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy");
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy", "org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyHbmImpl");
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.physical_naming_strategy", "com.example.config.HibernateLegacyImprovedNamingStrategy");

    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
    jpaProperties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.MULTI_TENANT, MultiTenancyStrategy.SCHEMA);
    jpaProperties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.MULTI_TENANT_CONNECTION_PROVIDER, multiTenantConnectionProvider);
    jpaProperties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.MULTI_TENANT_IDENTIFIER_RESOLVER, tenantIdentifierResolver);
    emfBean.setJpaPropertyMap(jpaProperties);
    return emfBean;
}
```

And provide implementations of `MultiTenantConnectionProvider` and `CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver`

As an example, for schema tenancy, the `CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver` could look up the current user from session to determine what schema to use.

The `MultiTenantConnectionProvider` could alter the connection with a command like `SELECT set_schema_to(?)` before returning the connection for use (and reset it on return).

```
@Override
public Connection getConnection(String tenantIdentifier) throws SQLException {
    final Connection connection = getAnyConnection();
    setSchemaTo(connection, tenantIdentifier);
    return connection;
}
```

You'll need to read up on multi-tenancy and see what type you want along with which implementations you are using.

Comment: Hi Glenn Thanks, I think this will solve my problem. I will give a try.